# Is it normal, that the GoogleMap API generates mutiple images for one Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, asp.net-core, google-maps-api-3

I have a special question to GoogleMaps...
I am on the way to develop a public portal with asp.net core 2.2 and use the Google Map API (with key) to show GoogleMaps on some pages.
I create the MAP (Sat) with the coordinates and set a marker with the address as title.
Anything works correct as you can see on the screenshot below **( 1 )**.
I'm now on the way to inspect the application in detail also with Google Chrom (Dev Environment) and thereby have seen a special (at least for me) behavior.
After the creation of the Map, GC shows, that two dynamic entries were generated:
**khms0.googleapis.com ( 2 )** and **khms1.googleapis.com ( 3 )**
Under both entries, **various links to images ( 2.1 )** and **( 3.1 )** where generated, whereby some of the images (example **( 2.2 )** ) are near the original location **( 1 )** but some not. 
I have investigated some other (foreign) web pages (with Maps) with GC and have seen the same behavior (same multiple image links).

[image: Screenshot Google Chrome]

Code snipped:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function GMEinfuegen() {
        var address = "@Model.cPAB_Strasse" + "," + "@Model.cPAB_PLZ" + " " + "@Model.cPAB_Ort"
        var addressTitle =  "@Html.Raw(@Model.cPAB_Firma)" + ", "  +   "@Html.Raw(@Model.cPAB_Strasse)" + ", " + "@Html.Raw(@Model.cPAB_PLZ)" + " " + "@Html.Raw(@Model.cPAB_Ort)"
        //
        var cLatituede = @Model.cPAB_Latituede
        var cLongituede = @Model.cPAB_Longituede
            function initMap() {
                @{ var tagname1 = "#map" + Model.PBA_Kundennummer;}
                var map = new google.maps.Map($("@tagname1")[0], {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: { lat: cLatituede, lng: cLongituede }, 
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                });
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    draggable: false, 
                    title: addressTitle,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: { lat: cLatituede, lng: cLongituede }
                });
            }
        initMap()
        } 
</script>
```

**Questions:**

- Is this the normal behavior?
- Can someone explain the reason for the further images?
- Since a while, the API calls have to be paid to google (if the free amount has exceeded) - I think (hope), the additional generated images don't count as API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your questions, indeed, this is expected behavior of Google Maps JavaScript API. The map is composed of multiple tile images, each one of size 256x256 pixels. So, the API makes multiple requests to tile imagery endpoints `khms0.googleapis.com` and `khms1.googleapis.com` to get tiles necessary for given viewport and zoom level. I would suggest having a look at the map tile coordinates documentation that explains this stuff in detail

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates

Each time you change zoom or pan the map, the API will send new requests to tile imagery endpoints and receive new tiles.

Referring to payment, Google Maps JavaScript API is not charged by tile imagery or any other operation like zoom, pan, etc. The payment is based on map loads. Google understands as a map load creation of the new instance of map in your code. In other words, they charge you for each `new google.maps.Map(options)` call in your JavaScript code.

In the following FAQ you can find more detailed explanation regarding map loads:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload

Also it is explained in Usage and Billing section of documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing#dynamic-maps

as you can see the SKU:Dynamic Map is incurred after calling `new google.maps.Map(options)`.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubts.

Comment: @Thanks for your useful and complete answer - it's nice to see that also such special questions are answered in no time with a good quality in SO :-)